# Processing for Android | save() "File contains a path separator"

Tags: java, android, processing

I'm using Processing 3.5.4.
I’m trying to `save()` an image of the screen to `data/frames` (relative to my sketch file). The code I’m using works in Java mode with no problems (I can see the image saving into the correct folder on my computer), but when running it on my Android device I get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File data/frames/frameasdf.tif contains a path separator`. I’m guessing this is because of a difference in file storage systems.

Is there any way I can avoid path separators other than saving images directly into the sketch folder?
I’m new to Java (just moved over from Javascript for more professional development), so if possible, please link to any helpful documentation.

```
PImage drawing;
void setup() {
  size(displayWidth, displayHeight);
}

boolean clicked = false;
String name = "asdf";

void mouseReleased() {
  clicked = true;
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  if(drawing != null) {
    image(drawing, 0, 0);
  }
  fill(0);
  noStroke();
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 50, 50);
  if(clicked) {
    save("data/frames/frame" + name + ".tif");
    drawing = loadImage("frames/frame" + name + ".tif");
  }

  clicked = false;
}
```

This is a shortened version of my code. It's a simple program that should add a dot to the screen whenever you click.
I do plan on saving more than one frame in the frames folder.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your question very well. Are you trying to save the file inside the specific app files or in shared storage files? the root files of the different storage systems can be got with Context.getExternalFilesDirs() that returns a vector with the files.

you can start reading the documentation here: [Android storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage)